# Can I connect a device to my SQL Server that is not on the same network?

Tags: sql, sql-server, api, xampp, connection

I'm doing an application using Angular + ASP.NET API + SQL server. This application works fine using local host and others devices connected on the same network, but I want to connect other device that is not on the same network, like a cellphone using 4g, is this possible? If it is, how can I do that? Xampp is a good option for this?

Comment: Is your database exposed in a way that you can connect to it from outside the network? If so you should be able to connect via the host.

Comment: with https://ngrok.com/ you can forward valid internet address to your localhost address

Comment: @SamOrozco How I can do that with my db? There is some way without having to pay a Cloud Db?

Comment: @barzin.A Thanks mate, I will see how it works!!!